# Numerically Stable Implementation

Tags: matlab, exp, numerical-stability

I need to compute a normalized exponential of a vector in Matlab.

Simply writing

```
res = exp(V)/sum(exp(V))
```

overflows in an element of V is greater than log(realmax) = 709.7827.
(I am not sure about underflow conditions.)

How should I implement it to avoid numerical instability?

Update: I received excellent responses about how to avoid overflow. However, I am still happy to hear your thoughts about the possibility of underflow in the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following approach avoids the overflow by *subtracting the exponents and then taking the exponential*, instead of dividing the exponentials:

```
res = 1./sum(exp(bsxfun(@minus, V(:), V(:).')))
```

As a general rule, overflow can be avoided by working in the log domain for as long as possible, and taking the exponential only at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to bsxfun. What if V is a matrix, and we want this to apply along dimension dim?

Comment: @user25004 How would that be? `exp(V)` would then be a matrix and `sum(exp(V),dim)` would be a vector. How do you define `exp(V)/sum(exp(V,dim))` in that case?

Comment: I mean if the variable called dim is 1,  I want your previous code to be applied to each column. If dim is 2, the code is applied row-wise.

Comment: @user25004 That would be harder. And it changes the question completely. The simple answer would be: loop over each row or column.

Comment: @user25004 Welcome! Feel free to ask that new requirement as a new question, if the loop solution is not good enough

Comment: Nice solution, should have a better precision than my solution.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is pretty similar to your previous question. Use Math!

```
exp(V)=exp(V-max(V))*exp(max(V))
sum(exp(V))=sum(exp(V-max(V))*exp(max(V)))=exp(max(V)*sum(exp(V-max(V))))
```

Putting both together:

```
res=exp(V-max(V))*exp(max(V))/exp(max(V)*sum(exp(V-max(V)))=exp(V-max(V))/sum(exp(V-max(V)))
```

A code which is robust to the input range:

```
res=exp(V-max(V))/sum(exp(V-max(V)))
```

Comment: Nice idea! Subtract the maximum